# React Context API & Lifecycle methods - How to use together

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm struggling to understand how to proceed with a small React app I am making.

I have a budget tracker, where you can add costs (mortgage, bills etc.) and they have a cost value. Each time you add, edit or delete one of these, I want the global state to change, which is stored in a context.

I basically have a 'remaining balance' value, that I want to recalculate each time something changes.

I figured I'd use a life cycle method or useEffect, but when I use that in my App.js (so that it watches for changes in all subcomponents), I can't get it to work, because the life cycle method is calling a method from my Context, but because it's not wrapped in the provider, it can't access the method in the Context.

Is this a common problem and is there are recommended way to fix it? I can't seem to find a similar problem on the GoOgLe.

App.js:

```
import React, { useState, useContext, useEffect } from "react";
import "./css/main.css";
import Header from "./layout/Header";
import BudgetInfo from "./components/BudgetInfo";
import PaymentForm from "./components/PaymentForm";
import CostToolbar from "./components/CostToolbar";
import Costs from "./components/Costs";

import BudgetContext from "./context/budgetContext";
import BudgetState from "./context/BudgetState";

const App = () => {

  const budgetContext = useContext(BudgetContext);

  const { updateBalance } = budgetContext;


  useEffect(() => {
    updateBalance();
  });

  return (
    <BudgetState>
      <Header darkModeToggle={toggleDarkMode} />
      <main
        className={"main-content" + (darkMode.darkMode ? " dm-active" : "")}
      >
        <div className="wrap content-wrap">
          <BudgetInfo />
          <PaymentForm />
          <CostToolbar />
          <Costs />
        </div>
      </main>
    </BudgetState>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: Could you provide some code ? and example ?

Comment: Yeah I'll add in some code, but I think my question is more of a concept than an actual error, but see my edited post for code.

Comment: do you have any of `<App>`'s parents include `<BudgetContext.Provider>`?

Comment: @skyboyer No  `<App>` is the top level component, which is then added to the #root in the index.html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap the App component. Try the simple example.

[image: Edit reverent-minsky-igvvr]

```
import React, { useEffect, useContext } from 'react';
import ThemeContext from './../context/context';

const Sample = () => {
  const context = useContext(ThemeContext);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(context,'--')
  },[])

  return(
    <ThemeContext.Consumer>
      {color => (
        <p style={{ color }}>
          Hello World
        </p>
      )}
    </ThemeContext.Consumer>
  )
}

export default Sample;
```

Comment: So I need to create a component above `<App>`, that imports the context and uses `<App>` in its render? and then mount that to the DOM instead?

Comment: I don't know exactly how did you define your provider and consumer but they are really important. you can access them in components which are wrapped in consumers ...

Comment: Marking this as correct answer as wrapping App in a new component called AppWrapper and mounting that to the DOM instead, and then using that component to import the Context and wrap the App component seemed to work.